# Paperclip - Image attributes not passed in the query INSERT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have all the default settings from paperclip's website. When I create a new application and put the settings in, once I save my model, the 'photo' paperclip attribute gets saves nicely, all is fine (here is the SQL INSERT sample):

```
"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f990a3d92d0
@original_filename="Screen Shot 2011-10-21 at 6.02.56 AM.png",
@content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"event[photo]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2011-10-21 at 6.02.56
AM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n"
```

and I get:

```
[paperclip] Saving attachments
```

Now in my app other app where I use Devise and Cancan, I have the exact same Paperclip setting, I do get the

```
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
```

But, **It does not save the 'photo' and  don't see the photo attributes getting defined**  at all.
Now I've seen a similar post that gets solved adding

```
attr_accessible photo
```

to the model, and I did that, and still it's not working.
I've been wasting so many hours on this, sometimes I feel like I should have just created my own image upload...

Any idea? Thx!

and by the way. Same issue on a **simple scaffold object** where I add

> attr_accessible :photo

Comment: I edited the post, explaining that it also happens on a freshly scaffolded object that's not using Devise nor Cancan. I'm sure you don't need to see that scaffold? It's just a standard scaffold with the 'photo' attribute. Works in a newly created app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a framework like jQuery Mobile or some sort of AJAX/PJAX mechanism, your uploads will be lost as POST in Ajax, since JS cannot read your local files...

You'll have to use some uploadify-like plugin or submit your form the "regular" way.

Edit:
To make things clear, the easiest way will be to add data-ajax="false" as a form attribute. In Rails 3, using the form helper, you'd write something along those lines:

```
<%= form_for (@my_object, html: {data: {ajax: false}}) do |f| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, I am using JQM. I'll have to find a different way of doing the file upload